# How can there be ambiguity between a property getter and a method with one argument?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, ambiguity

I can't believe I've never come across this before, but why am I getting a compiler error for this code?

```
public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        var ambiguous = new FooBar(1);
        var isConfused = ambiguous.IsValid; // this call is ambiguous
    }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public int DefaultId { get; set; }

    public FooBar(int defaultId)
    {
        DefaultId = defaultId;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return DefaultId == 0; }
    }

    public bool IsValid(int id)
    {
        return (id == 0);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

> Ambiguity between 'FooBar.IsValid' and 'FooBar.IsValid(int)'

**Why is this ambiguous?**

I'm thinking there are two reasons it should not be ambiguous:

1. There are no parenthases after `IsConfused`.
2. There is no int argument for `IsConfused`.

Where is the ambiguity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There error is because it is ambiguous since it's declared using `var`.  It could be:

```
bool isConfused = ambiguous.IsValid;
```

Or:

```
Func<int, bool> isConfused = ambiguous.IsValid;
```

Using `var` requires the compiler to be able to infer the exact meaning, and in this case, there are two possibilities.

However, if you remove the `var`, you'll still get a (different) error, since you can't have two members with the same name, one a property, and one a method.

Comment: There's also an error because you're simply not allowed to define two members with the same name :)

Comment: Was this constraint enforced since .Net 1?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, very true.  But the error he's displaying is the ambiguity due to the var...  I edited to mention that, too.

Comment: @Yuriy: Yes, though this message is newer than that, since `var` didn't exist in .NET 1.  The second error I mentioned would be the one he'd have received in early versions of .NET.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - Then, if the names are changed, the ambiguity wouldn't be there in the first place. I don't think this is a proper answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet @Reed Copsey - I am confused here. Of course VS displays the ambiguity error, but compilation gives only one error and I think only the latter should be the right one, because if the multiple members error is fixed, the ambiguity wouldn't be there at all.

Comment: @manojlds: Using the C# 4 compiler with this code, I only get an error of "The type 'FooBar' already contains a definition for 'IsValid'"

Comment: @manojlds: The compiler doesn't always show you ALL errors - often it will, but often it will stop when an error is encountered.  If you change `var` to `bool` in your line, as this suggests, you'll see the second error appear.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - exactly, that is what I am saying. So, VS is doing something wrong by displaying the other error right?

Comment: @manojlds: Are you using a productivity tool, like Resharper/JustCode/CodeRush?  If so, it's probably the tool reporting the wrong error...

Comment: @Jon, @manojlds: the engine that works out what the errors are *as you are typing* has subtly different behaviour than the engine that works out what the errors are *when you build*. In particular, the former tries to deal with situations where the code is incorrect *because it is being actively edited*. In these kinds of cases we have heuristics that try to detect and prevent "cascading" errors, where recovery from one error causes another; this might be an odd and unanticipated behaviour of one of those heuristics.

Comment: @Reed, +1 and thank you for your answer and additions. I don't think I've written a `Func` expression without using a lambda, so the scenario you mentioned never would have occurred to me. Interesting stuff.

Comment: The error happens despite properties are directly compiled to getter/setter methods named "PropertyName_get". It just means that at IL level you may have such a situation with omonymous method/property because you compile the method to IsValid(int) and property to IsValid_get(), which is still a method!

Answer (score 6):

It's confusing you would get that particular message, but it is not legal to have two members with the same name (excepting method overloading).  Here your property and method have the same name.   This is the same reason you can't have a property and an inner class with the same name.   Fields, properties, methods, and inner classes are all *members* of the enclosing type and must have unique names.

Comment: I think you've got it, +1. I was getting an error only on `Main` (not on `FooBar`), but when I commented out the offending line in `Main` and compiled, then I got an error for `FooBar` ('Foobar' already contains a definition for `IsValid`). It's strange that the error in main seems to cover up the error in `FooBar`.

Comment: @DanM - The other error is not covered. When I compile, I get only the other error, it is only VS that displays both the errors.

Comment: @DanM: It doesn't for me when compiling from the command line. Does it for you with *exactly* this code?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, @manojlds, You guys are right. I get only the error about ambiguity (red squiggle) before building, but after I build, the ambiguity error goes away, and I get only the "already contains a definition" error (blue squiggle).

Comment: Technically, though, properties ARE functions, which is why it's confusing. Java's Getter/Setter system has no such issues. Good explanation though, +1.

Comment: @Nyerguds, it would be more accurate to say that properties are *composed* of one or more functions.  They are first-class citizens of C# (unlike in Java).  In other words, property names can collide with other member names **and** the implied getter and setter methods can *also* collide with member names.  This is why `int Foo { get; set; }` and `int get_Foo() { return 0; }` will also cause a collision.

Comment: @KirkWoll: wow. Generated code added on compile time, and never shown to the user... how delightfully untransparent.

Comment: @Nyerguds, there is an enormous amount of that in C#, from closures, to expression trees, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would get an error that "FooBar already contains a definition for IsValid"

Comment: Strangely, I don't until I build. I get only the error about ambiguity (red squiggle). Once I build, the ambiguity error goes away, and I get the "already contains a definition" error (blue squiggle). Could this be a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: @DanM - that is what I was asking in the comments on @Reed Copsey's answer. VS seems to behave wrongly here. Actually, VS shows both the errors, compilation only shows the multiple definition error, which is what VS should have been showing as well.

Comment: @manojlds: question is, why would you get that message if the parameters are different? Seems like a simple overloaded name to me.

Answer (score -1):

At first, it might seem that the compiler could always figure out whether you're calling the method or using the property -- after all, the method has parentheses after it, and the property doesn't.

That doesn't hold up, though. You can use a method without the parentheses:

```
void Foo() { ... }
void Bar(Action action) { ... }

Bar(Foo);
```

And you can use a property *with* parentheses:

```
Action MyProperty { get; set; }

MyProperty();
```

The only way to make sure there's no ambiguity is to disallow having a method and a property with the same name.

Comment: You can't use a property with parentheses if its result is already defined as being a boolean, though.

Comment: First of all, that only addresses one of the situations where it's ambiguous. But second of all, you want to take a possible feature ("Allow properties to have the same names as methods") that's not very useful to begin with, and make it *less* useful by only allowing it when the property is of certain types? Remember, [every feature starts with minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). You're not presenting a very compelling case.