# Ambiguity between a property and a method

Tags: c#, inheritance

Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616136/how-can-there-be-ambiguity-between-a-property-getter-and-a-method-with-one-argum) i have something equal in my code. Let's say i have the following class:

```
public class EList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Add { get; set; }
}
```

now i'm expecting the error

> Ambiguity between 'EList.Add' and 'EList.Add(int)'

but the following code works without any errors:

```
EList<int> il = new EList<int>();
il.Add(1);
il.Add = "test";
```

Question: Does inheritance suppress this error by mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's explicitly catered for within the member lookup rules of C# ([C# Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) section 7.4). Specifically, what matters here is *invocability*

> *skipping earlier rules*
>
> - Next, if the member is invoked, all non-invocable members are removed from the set. (*The call to `Add()` is invoked. Therefore the `Add` property is removed from the set*)
> - Next, members that are hidden by other members are removed from the set. For every member S.M in the set, where S is the type in which the member M is declared, the following rules are applied:
>
>   - If M is a constant, field, property, event, or enumeration member, then all members declared in a base type of S are removed from the set. (*The `Add` method in the base type is removed*)
>
> *more rules*

So at this point, no ambiguity since the above two rules have eliminated one or other of the potentially conflicting members.

See also section 10.3, Class members:

> The name of a constant, field, property, event, or type must differ from the names of all other members declared in the *same* class.
>
> The name of a method must differ from the names of all other non-methods declared in the *same* class. In addition ...

(*My emphasis*)

And,

> The inherited members of a class type (§10.3.3) are not part of the declaration space of a class. Thus, a derived class is allowed to declare a member with the same name or signature as an inherited member

Comment: thank you that's the most plausible and best documented answer

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually gives a warning:

> Warning CS0108 'EList.Add' hides inherited member 'List.Add(T)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

There's no ambiguity here. `il.Add(1);` (because of `()`) is a method call. So compiler looks for method named `Add`. `il.Add = "test";` (because of `=`) is properties setter call. So compiler looks for property named `Add`.

So it seems that `Add` property override `Add` method. And then `il.Add(1);` and `il.Add = "test";` calls select best matching solution.

Comment: When you create a method and a property in the same class with the same name, you'll get the error. OP is asking why the error doesn't occur in case of inheritance.

Comment: if that would be the reason then this would compile: `public class EList2<T>{public string Add { get; set; }public void Add(int x){}}`

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity here as the Add property is defined in child class but the Add method is there in your parent class. The ambiguity is only there if you have members with same name within the same class.  Here the object you have created is of type `EList` and you are referring it by a variable of type `EList` so the compiler knows that there is one Add method defined which is in your parent class.Same case with the `Add` property also.

Even if you have defined another  `Add` method in `EList` there wont be any error just a warning stating that you are hiding an already implemented member from your base class.

This gives a more detailed info [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356(v=vs.71).aspx)

> The intuitive effect of the resolution rules described above is as follows: To locate the particular method invoked by a method invocation, start with the type indicated by the method invocation and proceed up the inheritance chain until at least one applicable, accessible, non-override method declaration is found. Then perform overload resolution on the set of applicable, accessible, non-override methods declared in that type and invoke the method thus selected.